# Better way of defining types for 'navigation' object, when using Stack Navigator in React Native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation, modularization

I'm having some trouble with modularization for the prop types, when using react-navigation.

My problem is:
[The React Navigation doc Typescript section](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/) suggests creating the types for each screen props like so:

```
//types.ts
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Profile: { userId: string };
  Feed: { sort: 'latest' | 'top' } | undefined;
};


// Profile.tsx
import type { NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import type { RootStackParamList } from  './types';

type ProfileProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Profile'>;
```

So, basically, importing the *NativeStackScreenProps* type, and passing both the *RootStackParamList*, and the page name, as a string.

But if I had to define prop types for another page in the same Stack, e.g. the *Home* page, I would have to repeat the SAME two type imports, which is not ideal, as far as I know.

All that changes is the string ('Profile', 'Home', etc) passed into the type.

```
// Home.tsx
import type { NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import type { RootStackParamList } from './types';

type HomeProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Home'>;
```

I'm kind of a beginner with TS, so my question is: How can I create a generic type that could help me avoid using the same two imports on every page? Since the only thing changing between these two prop types is a string.

Comment: All of this is in the documentation - it shows how to organize the types and all you need is a single import: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#organizing-types

Comment: Haven't noticed this section, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can abstract RootStackParamList and put it in a separate file. and export a generic type like below:

```js
export type RootStackProps<T extends keyof RootStackParamList> =
  NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, T>;
```

And use it like this:

```js
type HomeProps = RootStackProps<'Home'>;
```